# passing variable into contextmenustrip

Tags: vb.net, winforms

winforms app with 5 labels.
Each label is a variable pulled from an XML file.
I would like a right-click event to pull data into a contextmenustrip.

Right now I have it half successful. I can copy the url with a right click:

```
Private Sub Label1_Click(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Label1.MouseClick
    Dim x As String = Label1.Text
    If e.Button = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right Then
        Dim var As String = xmlinteraction.returnLink(x)
        Clipboard.SetText(var, TextDataFormat.Text)
    ElseIf e.Button = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left Then
        xmlinteraction.appCall(x)
    End If
End Sub
```

I would much prefer the user be prompted to see if they want to copy to clipboard, and if I can make that work I have three other menu item ideas I can easily use.
Can I could pass the copied variable into the first menu item of a contextmenustrip. So then I could create one contextmenustrip for all 5 labels and depending which label you right-click, it gives the correct value if you right-click then "Copy Link" from the contextmenustrip?

Comment: I figured out a way to do it by adding a contextmenustrip for each label. But there can be between 5 and 30 and I want it to be scaleable and not 30 contextmenustrips in one winform.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to have a separate `ContentMenuStrip` for each label.  You can apply the one `ContextMenuStrip` to every label.  Once you've done that you can easily determine which control it was that opened the menu from the menu's [Opening](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripdropdown.opening%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) event or from the [Click](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripitem.click%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) event of the `ToolStripMenuItem`

For example: if you were in the Opening event and wanted to find out which `Label` was right-clicked on so that you could add different menu items you just need to cast the [ContextMenuStrip.SourceControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.contextmenustrip.sourcecontrol%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) property:

```
Label clickedLabel = (Label)contextMenuStrip.SourceControl;
```

Once you're in the Click event and you want to find out which `Label` was right-clicked on you can just do it like this:

```
ContextMenuStrip contextMenu = (ContextMenuStrip)((ToolStripMenuItem)sender).Owner;
Label clickedLabel = (Label)contextMenu.SourceControl;
```

Comment: Opened new thread : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18415128/contextmenustrip-opening-event-determining-sender