# contextmenustrip opening event determining sender

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have 30 labels. They can have any value I want.
I need to be able to assign one context menu to them all then determine which label was clicked in order to use my `x`    variable.

```
    Private Sub Label_Click(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles       Label1.MouseClick, Label2.MouseClick, Label3.MouseClick, Label4.MouseClick, _
    Label5.MouseClick, Label6.MouseClick, Label7.MouseClick, Label8.MouseClick, Label9.MouseClick, Label10.MouseClick, Label11.MouseClick, _
    Label12.MouseClick, Label13.MouseClick, Label14.MouseClick, Label15.MouseClick, Label15.MouseClick, Label16.MouseClick, Label17.MouseClick, _
    Label18.MouseClick, Label19.MouseClick, Label20.MouseClick, Label21.MouseClick, Label22.MouseClick, Label23.MouseClick, Label24.MouseClick, _
    Label25.MouseClick, Label26.MouseClick, Label27.MouseClick, Label28.MouseClick, Label29.MouseClick, Label30.MouseClick
    
   Dim x As String = sender.Text
   xmlinteraction.appCall(x)
    End Sub
```

I received awesome help the other day [passing variable into contextmenustrip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18370545/passing-variable-into-contextmenustrip)
But I am too new to put it all together and make it work. I understand what we are trying to do, but not all the syntax. Please help.

---

Jay,
Here is what I put together from the code you gave me. Is this what you were thinking? I feel like I missing something still and further clean the code. Possibly removing the case statements.

```
   Private Sub rcmenuOption(x, y)
        ' x is equal to what the menu item was clicked
        ' Create case stament for that to call the correct xmlinteraction passing in y
        Select Case x
            Case "Copy Link"
                copyClipboard(y)
        End Select
    End Sub
    Private Sub rcmenuClicked(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItemClickedEventArgs) Handles rcmenu.ItemClicked
        ' Get the Label clicked from the SourceControl property of the clicked ContextMenuStrip.
        Dim contextMenu = DirectCast(sender, ContextMenuStrip)
        Dim label = DirectCast(contextMenu.SourceControl, Label)
        Dim var2 As String = label.Text
        ' Get the clicked menu strip and update its Text to the Label's Text.
        Dim toolStripItem = e.ClickedItem
        Dim var As String = toolStripItem.Text
        rcmenuOption(var, var2)
    End Sub
```

[contextmenustrip opening event determining sender](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18415128/contextmenustrip-opening-event-determining-sender)

Comment: My apologies, Phil.  The syntax I put in the last answer was actually C#.  My mistake.  The answer below should give you what you need.

Comment: I appreciate it Adrian and no problems... But now I am confusing myself even more. I understand what we are trying to do. I just don't know where I need to do the direct cast because I have no code to declare the right-click. Since I assigned the contextmenustrip to all labels, I dont know where that right click event is stored to cast. If I add it the the menustip opening, I receive an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, you have a number of `Labels` on a form and all of them use the same `ContextMenuStrip` (all the `Label`s have their `ContextMenuStrip` property set to the same `ContextMenuStrip` control).

When the user right clicks a `Label` and selects a menu item, you want that menu item's `Text` to change to the clicked `Label`'s `Text`.

You can do this using your `ContextMenuStrip` `ItemClicked` event handler.  Use the handler's sender and `ToolStripItemClickedEventArgs` parameters to get the `Label`'s `Text` and a reference to the `ToolStripItem` clicked.

```
Private Sub ContextMenuStrip1_ItemClicked(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItemClickedEventArgs) Handles ContextMenuStrip1.ItemClicked
    ' Get the Label clicked from the SourceControl property of the clicked ContextMenuStrip.
    Dim contextMenu = DirectCast(sender, ContextMenuStrip)
    Dim label = DirectCast(contextMenu.SourceControl, Label)

    ' Get the clicked menu strip and update its Text to the Label's Text.
    Dim toolStripItem = e.ClickedItem
    toolStripItem.Text = label.Text
End Sub
```

Comment: Where do I put the DirectCast? the x = sender in the above code is for the left click action of course. The code above is not to be altered and works perfectly. So when I declare x = directcast, where should that code go ?

Comment: Is that in the onload event of the contextmenustrip?

Comment: I will try it and see if I can figure it out. At this point, 8 hrs is totally ok and more than appreciated. What is going on, I have 15-30 labels. They are tied to an XML file with an appName and an appLink. So the label can have any name depending on some variables I have in place. So I need to get the label text, and pass that into my menustrip, so when you right click any of the labels and lets say change the appLink, it will change the correct one. I can provide more code and a more thorough explanation if need be. But if we are on the same page now, awesome.

Comment: @PhilJFry I steared you wrong with my comment, which I deleted.  I'm not entirely sure what you mean when you say passing your Label's Text into your menustrip but I updated my answer to show how you can get a reference to the Label that brought up the context menu.  In my sample I use that reference to set the context menu item's Text to the Label's text; let me know if I'm still off track!